# Widgets inside the canvas not being responsive to the screen

Tags: python, user-interface, customtkinter

```
class Taskcanvas(ctk.CTkCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.scroll_region = 5000

        # Canvas
        super().__init__(master=parent, bg=GRAY, height=500, width=290, highlightthickness=0,
                         scrollregion=(0, 0, 0, self.scroll_region))
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        #frame in the canvas
        self.create_window(0, 0, window=Taskframe(self, len(Task.Task_list)), anchor="nw")

        # Mouse scrolling probably won't use it but there anyway
        self.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: self.yview_scroll(-int(event.delta / 60), "units"))

        # Scrollbar
        scrollbar = ctk.CTkScrollbar(master=self, orientation="vertical", command=self.yview)
        self.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.place(relx=1, rely=0, relheight=1, anchor="ne")


class Taskframe(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, number_of_tasks):

        super().__init__(master=parent, fg_color=GRAY, width=280, height=5000)

        for tasks_row in range(number_of_tasks):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(tasks_row, weight=1)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #widgets
        Task(self)
        Task(self)


class Task(ctk.CTkFrame):
    Task_list = []

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Task.Task_list.append(self)

        super().__init__(master=parent, fg_color=LIGHT_GRAY, width=260, height=60)

        #trigger the event to view the task when clicked on it
        self.bind("<Button>", lambda event: print("display task"))

        self.grid(row=len(Task.Task_list), column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)
```

I want the widgets the TaskFrame and the Tasks to be responsive to the screen however I am not sure how to do it with the widgets inside a scrollable Canvas, I tried this but the program runs but the widgets are still not responsive, Any help Appreciated